# Firebase screen class name containing dots?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-analytics

I have set firebase analytics in my iOS application, in firebase console user engagement table is showing dots(..), in given image, Is there any solution for it?[image]

Comment: I think you have to scroll to adjust column width.

Comment: There is no horizontal scrolling, only vertical scrolling.

Comment: send me url,, let me check

Comment: firebase account is not open, i am passing logEvent: Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventSelectContent, parameters: [
                AnalyticsParameterItemID: "HomeView",
                "IP": ip,
                "UserEmail": email
            ])

Comment: This is a UI issue on Firebase Analytics UI. Team is aware of this gap and working on fixing it.